# Docker pull command fails in the middle of a pull operation

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster in Azure. In the cluster I exec into a pod and try to pull a docker image from a private Azure container registry (ACR) named `xxx`. Before the pulls, I logged in via `docker login` using a service principal that has pull access to that private ACR.

When I pull a small image, it works ok:

```
runner@arc-runner-set-nkb6b-runner-dtcnv:~$ docker pull xxx.azurecr.io/hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from hello-world
1b930d010525: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:92c7f9c92844bbbb5d0a101b22f7c2a7949e40f8ea90c8b3bc396879d95e899a
Status: Downloaded newer image for xxx.azurecr.io/hello-world:latest
xxx.azurecr.io/hello-world:latest
runner@arc-runner-set-nkb6b-runner-dtcnv:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                               TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
xxx.azurecr.io/hello-world   latest    fce289e99eb9   5 years ago   1.84kB
```

But, when I attempt to pull a larger image (the one below weights 1.24GB) from the same ACR, the pull breaks in the middle. It downloads some of the layers and then fail with `pull access denied` error, like below:

```
runner@arc-runner-set-nkb6b-runner-dtcnv:~$ docker pull xxx.azurecr.io/infrastructure-github-actions-image:latest
latest: Pulling from infrastructure-github-actions-image
31bd5f451a84: Pull complete
c775818794e7: Pull complete
5cf300f11d84: Pull complete
eb81f54b01af: Pull complete
f3a184abd17b: Downloading
dc1168a60e35: Downloading
5d3d464daf1d: Download complete
9a8c0a4ab53e: Download complete
0c1136627dd1: Download complete
pull access denied for xxx.azurecr.io/infrastructure-github-actions-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: {"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"requested access to the resource is denied"}]}
```

Other observations:

- I can successfully pull the `xxx.azurecr.io/infrastructure-github-actions-image:latest` image locally (on my local laptop)
- On the k8s pod I can successfully pull any image (big or small) from the docker hub:

```
runner@arc-runner-set-gs4q4-runner-vggj5:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                               TAG                  IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
cimg/android                                             2024.01.1-browsers   4bf6cdd305c8   3 weeks ago    7.3GB
openjdk                                                  21                   079114de2be1   4 months ago   504MB
xxx.azurecr.io/hello-world   6d3df195e8           fce289e99eb9   5 years ago    1.84kB
```

I'm out of ideas why the operation fails in the middle. Anyone stumbled upon such a problem or have any suggestions on what else I can do to debug this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. To anyone that stumbles upon the same thing let me explain where was the problem:

The `docker pull` command I was running from a container requires docker daemon to be present. Docker daemon was provided by another container collocated within the same pod named `docker:dind` (where dind means docker in docker), it's from here: (https://hub.docker.com/_/docker).

The problem was the most recent `docker:dind` distribution `25.0.3`. I downgraded dind to `docker:24-dind` and the pull works correctly now.

I didn't have time yet to do deeper into the problem, but I hope I will.

Thanks anyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Opinionated but empirical answer (the same happened to me).

The message usually comes when you put the wrong image name. Please check if your image has the correct name and tag on the Azure ECR repository. You probably use shell autocompletion with the wrong history added on the first machine; on another machine, it's fine. Recheck all symbols carefully or try to run the same command from another shell/terminal (probably a bad symbol somewhere).

Comment: Thanks. I check it carefully. Please note that I manage to pull some of the image layers before the error pops up. This would not be a case if there would be a typo somewhere in the command.

Comment: Could it be someone who restricted permissions on Azure ECR for you? You can check this and try to docker (re)login or, better, generate new creds (just to play around to see what happens).

Comment: Not really, these creds are currently used by other service (Jenkins) to essentially do the same thing - that is pull images from that ACR. Also, please note that with these creds I can pull a complete tiny hello-world image from that ACR.

I don't know, to me it feels like something interfere with traffic between k8s and ACR. I wonder if that could be some security stuff enforced on organization level (like real-time traffic monitoring).. something I cannot see from my azure subscription.

Comment: Also, I tried different set of creds, and the same happens.